# SQL Server getting main/parent blocking session id from a blocking session chain

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to find the parent blocking session from a blocking session chain and I have found below from [here](https://www.sqlshack.com/resolve-and-troubleshoot-sql-blocking-chain-with-root-session/):

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
SELECT session_id, blocking_session_id
FROM SYS.DM_EXEC_REQUESTS
WHERE session_id > 49 and blocking_session_id <> 0
 
UNION ALL
 
SELECT X.blocking_session_id AS session_id, ISNULL(Y.blocking_session_id, 0) AS blocking_session_id
FROM CTE X
OUTER APPLY [fn_get_blocking_session](X.blocking_session_id) Y
WHERE X.blocking_session_id <> 0
)
 
SELECT DISTINCT sdes.session_id, host_name, program_name, sqltext.TEXT, dmv.wait_type, dmv.wait_resource
FROM CTE c
INNER JOIN SYS.dm_exec_sessions sdes ON c.session_id = sdes.session_id
LEFT JOIN sys.dm_exec_requests dmv ON c.session_id = dmv.session_id
OUTER APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(dmv.sql_handle) AS sqltext
WHERE c.blocking_session_id = 0
```

Above query uses a function called fn_get_blocking_session but It does not seem to be a system function since SQL Server does not recognize it. Maybe it is a custom function? Or could someone provide me a similar way to get the parent blocking session id from a blocking session chain?

Comment: Please create function using --

CREATE FUNCTION fn_get_blocking_session (@in BIGINT)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
SELECT * FROM SYS.DM_EXEC_REQUESTS WHERE session_id = @in

Answer (score 1):

We are using this query as a view. It has some information about blocking. (NOLOCK-s probably aren't needed)

```sql
SELECT d.name [db]
  , l.rsc_indid            [index_id]
  , l.req_spid             [spid]
  , p.blocked              [blocked_by]
  , p2.blocked             [blocked_by_by]
  ,CASE l.rsc_type
    WHEN 2 THEN 'Database'
    WHEN 3 THEN 'File'
    WHEN 4 THEN 'Index'
    WHEN 5 THEN 'Table'
    WHEN 6 THEN 'Page'
    WHEN 7 THEN 'Key'
    WHEN 8 THEN 'Extent'
    WHEN 9 THEN 'Row'
    WHEN 10 THEN 'Application' END [LockObjType]
  ,CASE l.req_mode
    WHEN 1 THEN 'Sch-S'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'Sch-M'
    WHEN 3 THEN 'S'
    WHEN 4 THEN 'U'
    WHEN 5 THEN 'X'
    WHEN 6 THEN 'IS'
    WHEN 7 THEN 'IU'
    WHEN 8 THEN 'IX'
    WHEN 9 THEN 'SIU'
    WHEN 10 THEN 'SIX'
    WHEN 11 THEN 'UIX'
    WHEN 12 THEN 'BU'
    WHEN 13 THEN 'RangeS_S'
    WHEN 14 THEN 'RangeS_U'
    WHEN 15 THEN 'RangeI_N'
    WHEN 16 THEN 'RangeI_S'
    WHEN 17 THEN 'RangeI_U'
    WHEN 18 THEN 'RangeI_X'
    WHEN 19 THEN 'RangeX_S'
    WHEN 20 THEN 'RangeX_U'
    WHEN 21 THEN 'RangeX_X' END [lock_type]
  ,CASE l.req_status
     WHEN 1 THEN 'G'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'C'
    WHEN 3 THEN 'W' END [status]
  ,CASE l.req_ownertype
    WHEN 1 THEN 'Transaction'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'Cursor'
    WHEN 3 THEN 'Session'
    WHEN 4 THEN 'ExSession' END [lock_ownertype]
  ,p.loginame
  ,p.hostname
  ,p.program_name
  ,l.req_refcnt
  ,p.cmd
  ,p.waittime
  ,p.sql_handle
  ,p2.sql_handle [sql_handle_blocking]

  ,l.rsc_objid   [objectID]
  ,l.rsc_dbid    [dbid]
FROM sys.syslockinfo l
JOIN sys.sysprocesses p ON l.req_spid=p.spid
LEFT JOIN sys.sysprocesses p2 ON p.blocked = p2.spid
JOIN sys.sysdatabases d ON d.dbid = l.rsc_dbid
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.sysobjects o ON o.id = l.rsc_objid
```